# LinkedIn Post Deleted After Successfully Posting

Tags: linkedin-api

I've been using the Marketing API to make posts on behalf of our users using the [create post API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/posts-api?view=li-lms-2023-10&tabs=http#create-a-post)

`POST https://api.linkedin.com/rest/posts`

For the most part have no issues but recently have been seeing something weird where very intermittently where we'll get a successful response with a UGC URN returned, but then we'll notice that the link ends up not working with a generic error

An example this one https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:ugcPost:7125874324170764290/ which was allegedly posted now leads to a generic error page and no other way I could have gotten the URN except from a successful post

My current theory is that the copy that was supposed to be posted here for this user was also posted on an organization account at the same time and maybe both were actually posted but then deleted as some kind of spam filter because of the exact match of the post

Any idea if that's something LinkedIn does or any other ideas what might be happening? I've confirmed with the users that they haven't manually deleted the post and out of ideas for what might by the issue